# Digital PCB Plans for Retro Computers

Tags: hardware, amiga, commodore

I use software like Fritzing or Autodesk EAGLE to draw my Raspberry Pi or Arduino projects and was wondering if there is a source for PCB plans of for example an Amiga 500 in a format readable for such software?

I'm currently working on an old Commodore PC and only found PDF scans of plans from manuals, that are hard to read.

Comment: https://www.amigapcb.org/ has a pretty complete PCB viewer for most Amiga models if it helps. There's also  folks who reverse engineered the Amiga 4000 and 1200 PCBs and uploaded PCB design files for them. Here's the 4000 rev B for example: https://github.com/Acill/A4000RevB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been several attempts on things like this. For the Amiga there are for example:

- Re-Amiga http://wordpress.hertell.nu/?p=587
- A4000TX http://www.amibay.com/showthread.php?101477-A4000TX-ATX-Amiga-motherboard

And there were older examples as well, some of which got lost in time.

There are also examples for IBM PCs, sometimes designed from scratch, sometimes reverse engineered.

- Various PC cards and XT mainboards: http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergeys-projects
- Adlib clone https://github.com/schlae/adlib
- SoundBlaster clone https://github.com/schlae/snark-barker

And there are many more examples in the homebrew community.

If you only want to explore Amiga PCBs, there is http://www.amigapcb.org/ -- it has quite a bunch of mainboards.